# Find the value of textfield1 to textfield2 javascript and see the textfield1 equivalent value from textfield3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am not a javascript experT but I wanted to implement something like

there a textfield named textfield1 where the user will input 10digits
then what the user will input will compare to textfield2 if it is inside the textfield2 actually I can do that however I have textbox3 that corresponds to each value of textfield2 the textfield2 and 3 are autopopulated by query so I am not the one inputing it

example I typed in texfield1

value:

```
1234567890
```

textfield2 has a value of

```
4567891000;123456789;55555555
```

textfield3 has value of

```
f1;x1;c1
```

it is in order as textfield2 so the equivalent value is based in order

wherein

```
4567891000 = f1
123456789 = x1
55555555 =c1
```

my code is below

```
 function StringSearch() {

  var SearchTerm = document.getElementById('textfield1').value;
  var TextSearch = document.getElementById('textfield2').value;

  if ((SearchTerm.match(/^\d{10}$/)) && TextSearch.indexOf(SearchTerm) > -1) {
    alert("textfield1 " + SearchTerm +" Exists in textfield2");

  } else {
     alert("textfield1 " + SearchTerm +" Not Exists in textfield2");

  }
}
</script>
```

the current output is just checking whether it exist it will give alert message

1234567890

```
textfield1 1234567890 Exists in textfield2
```

but I wanted the result to be like

```
 textfield1 1234567890 Exists in textfield2 equivalent value is x1 from textfield3
```

I will really appreciate any advice or help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` to convert your textfield values to array and then find equivalent value based on index

```js
  function StringSearch() {

        var SearchTerm = document.getElementById('textfield1').value;
        var TextSearch = document.getElementById('textfield2').value;
        var TextSearch3 = document.getElementById('textfield3').value;

        if (TextSearch.indexOf(SearchTerm) > -1) {
            var text2Values = TextSearch.split(';');
            var text3Values = TextSearch3.split(';');
            alert("textfield1 " + SearchTerm + " Exists in textfield2 and equivalent value is " + text3Values[text2Values.indexOf(SearchTerm)] +" from text3");

        } else {
            alert("textfield1 " + SearchTerm + " Not Exists in textfield2");

        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textfield1" value="123456789" />
<input type="text" id="textfield2" value="4567891000;123456789;55555555" />
<input type="text" id="textfield3" value="f1;x1;c1" />
<button onclick="StringSearch()">Search</button>
```

Comment: Thank you you are great!

Comment: Happy to help :)